# Maxpedition Condor 2 unresolved questions

Tags: backpacking, backpacks

I am undecided between sitka and condor 2 packs. Can you please answer few of my question so I can deicide on my purchase.

1. How much can condor 2 be shrunk when all 4 side compression straps are pulled as much as they allow (when main compartment is almost empty)? Will it be thinner than Sitka?
2. Do all condor 2 bags have that ruberry bottom or not (read different stories about that)? I am looking to order from amazon, foliage green version.
3. From the youtube videos I see on some that zippers are turned inwards into the bag so the dust can not get stuck between the zip teeth and on some videos it is the other way around. What is the status with the current condor 2 bags?
4. Can 13 inch macbook air be put in the condor 2 compartment for camel back (water compartment)?
5. Also regarding the size comparison between condor 2 and sitka : Can sitka pack 1 pair of sport shoes, towel, t-shirt, 2 medium sized lunch boxes (not to big) in the main compartment, beside ordinary small stuffs and bottle in other compartments?

Comment: Oh goodness, folks. I'm not sure asking very specific questions about the capabilities of an outdoor product is anything like the "shopping recommendation" concerns discussed in this post: [Q&A is hard. Let's go shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/). It's your call, but this seems like a very unfortunate turn for this site. This is ***exactly*** the type of question I might have asked about my gear, and the type of deeper gear discussions that would be the mainstay of any *decent* "Outdoors" site.

Comment: @RobertCartaino I ended ordering Condor 2 and find it pretty much perfect for my needs. And answers are 1. Pretty slim, about 5-8cm. 2. It have rubbery bottom. 3. Zips are turned inwards, nice. 4. It can, and it is padded on the back, perfect. 5. IDK about Sitka, do not have it

Comment: @SašaŠijak -- Thank you for replying with the results of your purchase.  I was curious myself.

Comment: Considering that outdoors.SE is close to being a ghost town, I don't think we should be going out of our way to turn away new users who ask reasonable questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ended ordering Condor 2 and find it pretty much perfect for my needs. 
And answers are :

1. Pretty slim, about 5-8cm. But beware that the bag is so stiff and sturdy that this is not an easy task.
2. It has a rubbery black bottom which grips better to surfaces and protects from moisture. A nice thing is that the bag always stays upright when I put it on the floor, even when it is empty, because of this bottom and stiffness.
3. Zips are turned inwards, which is good because it protects the teeth of the zip from water and particles.
4. A MacBook Air 13 inch can easily go into the camelbag compartment and that compartment is padded on the back. Maybe some 15 inch slim laptops can fit to but I do not have one to try.

I can't answer the last question concerning the Sitka because I decided to buy the Condor.